# How can I call function 1 time only with Android service?

Tags: android, android-service

Please read carefully because it is a little bit complicated!

I have a service that call many functions every 5 second. Now I want to call one specific fucntion in those functions just 1 time only. So I make this to check if that function has called before.

```
private void checkFirstLaunchApp() {
    final String HAS_RUN_BEFORE = "hasRunBefore";
    final String HAS_RUN = "hasRun";

    SharedPreferences runCheck = getSharedPreferences(HAS_RUN_BEFORE, 0); 
    Boolean hasRun = runCheck.getBoolean(HAS_RUN, false);
    if (!hasRun) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(HAS_RUN_BEFORE, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(HAS_RUN, true); //set to has run
        edit.apply(); //apply

        //do that function
        functionIWant();
        }

    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

But the problem is if I close my app and reopen it,that function will not be called anymore. What I want is when I reopen my app, that function will be called 1 time again.Please show me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to reset `HAS_RUN` to false inside `onStart()` of your launcher activity.
**Alternate**
Extend Application class and create global variable:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
   public boolean hasRun;
   public void onCreate (){
        hasRun=false;
   }
}
```

Get instance of MyApplication

```
MyApplication app=(MyApplication)getApplication();
if(!app.hasRun){
   app.hasRun=true;
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Where exactly would this script be placed?

Answer (score 2):

Use global variable instead of SharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

Handle it in the [onResume](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) method

Answer (score 0):

A field variable is fine, sharedpreferences is not suitable for this case.

```
private boolean mIsCalled;
...
private void functionIWant() {
    if (mIsCalled) return;
    mIsCalled = ture;
    // your function body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `SharedPreference` to false in `onStop()` method :

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(HAS_RUN_BEFORE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(HAS_RUN, true); //set to has run
    edit.apply(); //apply
```

Call your method in `onResume()` method :

```
    checkFirstLaunchApp()
```